# Overloading operators :: HaskellNewbie

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm making a new type so I can calculate big numbers with some precision. Basically its a Double and a Integer to represent a number as `Double * 10 ^ Integer`. Now I began to make the program and it was going "ok" till I tried to make a instance of my new number so I could simple use `+` to add my new numbers up. This makes it easier for me to use in my existing programs. But I'm just getting a errors along the lines of "Could not deduce" from my code (I'll post an example below).  I somewhat understand the error, but I can seem to get around the problem. If you wish to compile the code, comment lines 4 and 5.

I'v been working on this for hours and is "killing" me.

```
newtype Sci f p = Sci (f ,p)  deriving (Eq,Show) 


instance (Floating a,Integral b) => Num (Sci a b) where
   Sci (a,b) * Sci (c,d) = fixSci( Sci(a*c,b*d) )


mulSci :: Sci Double Integer -> Sci Double Integer -> Sci Double Integer
mulSci (Sci(a,b)) (Sci(c,d)) = fixSci (Sci(a*c,b*d))


mkSci :: Double -> Sci Double Integer   
mkSci 0 = Sci(0, 0)
mkSci n = let lg = (floor ((log10 . abs) n)) in Sci((n/(10**(fromIntegral lg))), if lg > 0 then lg else 0)

fixSci :: Sci Double Integer -> Sci Double Integer
fixSci (Sci(a,b)) = let n = mkSci a in (\(Sci(c,d)) -> Sci(c,b+d)) n

fromSci (Sci(a,b)) = a*10**(fromIntegral b)

showSci (Sci(a,b)) = (show a)++"e"++(show b) 

lx :: Double
lx = log 10

log10 :: Double -> Double
log10 y = log y / lx


-- ~ main = putStrLn $ showSci $ fixSci $ Sci(95,0)
main = putStrLn $ showSci $ mkSci 95
```

Here is an example error:

```
sci.hs:5:40:
   Could not deduce (a ~ Double)
   from the context (Floating a, Integral b)
     bound by the instance declaration at sci.hs:4:10-49
     `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
         the instance declaration at sci.hs:4:20
   In the first argument of `(*)', namely `a'
   In the expression: a * c
   In the first argument of `Sci', namely `(a * c, b * d)'

sci.hs:5:44:
   Could not deduce (b ~ Integer)
   from the context (Floating a, Integral b)
     bound by the instance declaration at sci.hs:4:10-49
     `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
         the instance declaration at sci.hs:4:31
   In the first argument of `(*)', namely `b'
   In the expression: b * d
   In the first argument of `Sci', namely `(a * c, b * d)'
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: "But I'm just getting a errors from my code." Have you tried reading the errors, and reducing the problem to its core? Note that both errors refer to line 5.

Comment: It would also help if you posted the errors that you're getting.  I can see one immediate problem where you've neglected to implement the minimum complete definition of the `Num` typeclass.  You also need `+`, `-` or `negate`, `abs`, and `signum` (I think that's all, but check the docs to be sure)

Comment: Would the [scientific](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scientific-0.1.0.0) package be useful instead?

Comment: "I am getting errors.", "It doesn't work." and phrases like this are no actual problem descriptions. Indeed, if it were, we could reduce 95% of all SO postings to the following "I wrote something in some language I am a newbie in, but it doesn't work."

Comment: Oops, I will edit the question. Yes the scientific package would work very well, but I was trying to learn something from making the code (probably in a very bad idea).

Comment: Post the error messages.

Comment: Remove all of your explicit type annotations and change the instance declaration to `(RealFrac a, Floating a,Integral b) => Num (Sci a b)`. Write the function `mul (Sci (a,b)) (Sci (c,d)) = fixSci( Sci(a*c,b*d) )` and do `:t mul` with and without your type annotations.

Comment: Fwiw, `(Int64, Int64)` seems cleaner than `(Double, Integer)` to store your components

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Admittedly, reading and understanding GHC error messages is not easy. Therefore, your question is valid.

Obviously, the messages are referring to your definition of the `*` operator. We can tell this from the line number mentioned in `sci.hs:5:40` and from the fact that (*) is the only one you defined in your Num instance.

Remember the general type of `*`, it is

```
(*) :: Num n => n -> n -> n
```

which means: For all types n that have a Num instance, if you give 2 values of that type to `*`, you will get back another value of same type. Or simpler: (`*`) will work for any numeric type, as long as the factors are of the same type and the result will have the same type as the factors.

Needless to say, your implementation of `*` must fulfill this contract. And because your `Sci` type itself is polymorphic, your incarnation has the type:

```
(*) :: (Floating a, Integral b) => Sci a b -> Sci a b -> Sci a b
```

So your are claiming that your multiplication will work for type `Sci a b` for any types a and b, as long as a is a Floating type and b is an Intergal type. That is, it should work for `Sci Float Int` as well as for `Sci Double Integer`.

By now, you should already know what the error is: Your implementation doesn't live up to that promise. In fact, it only works for `Sci Double Integer`, because your helper function `fixSci` can only work with `Sci Double Integer`.

The error message tries to tell you just that, in a more technical form. It lists

1. the type conflict `a` vs `Double` ("You promised to give me anything, but all I got was a lousy Double!")
2. the constraints actually in scope ("You said, `a` was an instance of `Floating`) and where it was introduced.
3. The expression(s) that led the compiler to infer `Double`

Unfortunately, the compiler stops short (for brevity, as it is known that newbies never read error messages anyway :) before the interesting part. It could have included something like

```
in the expression fixSci (Sci (a*c) (b*d)), 
and since fixSci takes an argument of type Sci Double Integer
I concluded that Sci (a*c) (b*d) must be  Sci Double Integer
and hence (a*c) must be Double.
```

Comment: This is very nice, thanks for the response, I only vaguely understood the other similar problems on SO. Sometime the other responses were rather intimidating.

Answer (score 0):

Not really related to your question, but to your code:

Should it really be `mulSci (Sci(a,b)) (Sci(c,d)) = fixSci (Sci(a*c,b*d))`?
Shouldn't it be `b+d` instead of `b*d`?

Why don't you just set `newtype Sci = Sci Double Integer`?
Then you would have

```
instance Num Sci where
    (Sci m1 e1) * (Sci m2 e2) = fixSci (Sci (m1*m2) (e1+e2))
    (Sci m1 e1) + (Sci m2 e2) = <some rather complicated expression>
```

Comment: You would need `data` here, or leave the tuple.

Comment: Oh... Yes, you're right, `newtype` can only wrap *one* type (though it may be a composite type), not several as in my code.

Comment: Thanks, this was a good example of how my could should have looked. I based my solution off of this. Yeah, that's one of several mistakes in my code, ill fix it up for others future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Not your original question, but your `showSci` function bothers me:

Don't derive Show, write your own show function:

```
instance Show Sci where
    show (Sci (a,b)) = (show a) ++ "e" ++ (show b)
```

Then `main` becomes:

```
main = print $ mkSci 95
```

Comment: I derived show because I wanted a raw view of a Sci type, I also didn't know how to do what you said above. I plan on making a show function that looks like how a float is printed. Thanks for the tip